# how to return 2 highest score and 2 lowest score based on a data frame in r?

Tags: r, max

I have given a bunch of data about scores, I already combined them and calculated the mean, also arrange them from highest to lowest all with using dplyr and %>%
however I am trying to output 2 the highest score and the lowest score without using any number ( I mean do not want to use a for loop ><= a specific number)
it is easy to do the 1 the highest and 1 the lowest but have no idea how to do it for 2!
can someone help me? thanks

Comment: Hi @Sarah MN, Welcome to Stack!  Don't forget to read the help center section on [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). tl:dr - If you feel like the answers below are valid (i.e. answered your question) please upvote them and make sure to also use the check next to the one that you feel best answers your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

# Create an example data set

df <- tribble(~name, ~score,
              'John', 10,
              'Mike', 2,
              'Mary', 11, 
              'Jane', 1,
              'Jill', 5)


df %>% 
  arrange(score)  %>% 
  slice(1:2, nrow(.) - 1:0)

# name  score
# <chr> <dbl>
# 1 Jane      1
# 2 Mike      2
# 3 John     10
# 4 Mary     11
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use dplyr’s `top_n()` function.

`top_n(your_variable, 2)` returns the 2 highest scores and `top_n(your_variable, -2)` the lowest two.

The variable doesn’t need to be sorted first.

https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/top_n.html

Answer (score 1):

In base R, we can use `order` to order the data based on `scores`. To get top 2 and bottom 2 `scores`, we use `head` and `tail`

Using @TonyLadson's data

```
inds <- order(df$score)
df[c(head(inds, 2), tail(inds, 2)), ]

#  name  score
#  <chr> <dbl>
#1 Jane      1
#2 Mike      2
#3 John     10
#4 Mary     11
```

To subset the data without re-arranging and maintaining the same order, we can also do

```
df[inds %in% c(1, 2, nrow(df) - 1, nrow(df)), ]
```

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  arrange(score) %>%
  filter(row_number() %in% c(1, 2, n() - 1, n()))
```